# maven glassfish plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, glassfish

I am trying to deploy a war file using glassfish maven plugin However I end up with the following exception:

```
**SEVERE: WebModule[/myapp]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.maven.PluginUtil.doDeploy(PluginUtil.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.maven.AbstractDeployMojo.doDeploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.maven.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)**
```

I googled around and found out the reason may be because of multiple copies of the asm jar getting loaded. The asm jar is not a direct dependency for my project but is an indirect dependency through another project that my project depends on.  MyProject->AnotherProject who's dependency is asm jar.

When I create the WAR via maven war plugin, it inserts the asm jar in the lib folder for the webapp. I tried to force it to exclude this by doing the following in my pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <packagingExcludes>asm*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Still no luck ! Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not simply exclude those jars. It will be a runtime issue if you project actually depends on it. I suggest you following these steps:

1. Find out which artifact this class belonged to. In you case, my guess is "objectweb.asm".
2. Use maven-dependency-plugin to find out how many different version of "objectweb.asm" you project depends on:

   ```
    mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:objectweb.asm
   ```
3. Pick the most appropriate one and exclude other in your pom, e.g. :

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>xxxGroup</groupId>
           <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
           <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                        <groupId>anotherGroup</groupId>
                        <artifactId>anotherXXX</artifactId>                                              
                  </exclusion>
           </exclusions>           
       </dependency>
   ```